# Is there any gas cost when executing `msg.sender.transfer(0)`?

Tags: solidity, gas, address.transfer

I have a function which looks more or less like this:

```
function exchange(uint256 amount, bool specialCase) external returns (uint256) {
    let retVal;
    if (specialCase) {
        register(amount);
        retVal = 0;
    }
    else if (amount > address(this).balance) {
        register(amount - address(this).balance);
        retVal = address(this).balance;
    }
    else {
        register(0);
        retVal = amount;
    }
    require(authorized(msg.sender));
    msg.sender.transfer(retVal);
    return retVal;
}
```

As you can see, in some cases, it will execute `msg.sender.transfer(0)`.

Of course, I can avoid this by placing `msg.sender.transfer(retVal)` only where `retVal > 0`.

But I think that my code looks "cleaner" this way, and I would like to keep it as is.

So I would like to know if there is any gas cost in executing `msg.sender.transfer(0)`.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cost about 1200 gas according to remix.

using this contract:

```
contract test  {
    address user = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c;

    function send() public {
        user.transfer(0);
    }
}
```

Produces a transaction cost of 22381 gas, with execution cost of  1173 gas

Changing the value of the transfer to anything different from zero (note that the contract must have a positive balance) make the execution cost about 8000.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact it does help. Thank you very much for running it on Remix!!!

Comment: To add to this: `transfer` does a call into the contract with a 2300 gas stipend, so if the `transfer` is too a contract, it can cost up to 2300 gas.